# Retrieve an embedded array and return as a collection of object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm just starting with mongodb.

Is it possible to query the embedded array of "items" objects from below in an aggregate stage

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5fdbea7c15e31a000858e345"),
        "orderno": "111",
        "items": [
            {
                "linenum": 1,
                "itemcode": "item1"
            },
            {
                "linenum": 2,
                "itemcode": "item2"
            },
            {
                "linenum": 3,
                "itemcode": "item3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

so it can be returned as a collection of objects?

```
[
    {
        "linenum": 1,
        "itemcode": "item1"
    },
    {
        "linenum": 2,
        "itemcode": "item2"
    },
    {
        "linenum": 3,
        "itemcode": "item3"
    }
]
```

Everything I tried so far always embed the array in a document like below

```
[
    {
        "items": [
            {
                "linenum": 1,
                "itemcode": "item1"
            },
            {
                "linenum": 2,
                "itemcode": "item2"
            },
            {
                "linenum": 3,
                "itemcode": "item3"
            }
        ]   
    }
]
```

thanks

Comment: Use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to make each array element its own document, then [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) if desired to lift the array element to top level.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking